# How do I determine the frequency of $x(t) = 9\cos(2t) + 4\sin(\pi t)$

Tags: periodic-functions

The question I need to answer is what is the period of that function. The equation I know for period is $T = \frac{2\pi}{f}$ but I don't know how to figure out the frequency in that function. Looking at the graph of this function it seems the period is $7\pi$.

Comment: $x(t)$ is not periodic. Perhaps the $2t$ was meant to be $2\pi t$?

Comment: Are you sure that the function is periodic?

Comment: I put the function into Mathway.com and had it to graph it. Like I said it looks periodic with the period being 7π. I copied the function as it was given to me.

Comment: You can check by calculator to see if $x(0)=x(7\pi)$.  If not, then that is not the period.

Comment: $2$ and $\pi$ are not rational multiples of each other.

Comment: thank you all! I appreciate all the help!